# How to handle validity based permission in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, permissions

In my Django application users have access based on the subscription plan they opt-in, let's say I have a plan called `Project Lite`, whenever user purchase the plan I will be adding the user to a group called `Lite` which has a set of permission, such `can_add_attachment`.

In my views, I will check permission like `user.has_perm('can_add_attachment')`. which works fine, but the problem is `Project Lite` plan is valid for `1 year` after that user will not be allowed to access the view, how to handle this scenario

Is it ok if we extend UserGroup like this

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
     user =  models.ForeignKey(User)
     group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
     expires_at = models.DateTimeField()

class User(AbstractUser):
     groups = models.ManyToMany(Group, throguh="UserGroup")
```

or is there some other method we should use?

Comment: You need to setup a cron job which will regularly check and remove users from group.

Comment: ya this is one solution, I have updated my question now, is it ok if we use groups using through model

Answer (score 0):

A typical RDBMS implementation of your problem is the following:

You have a `user` Model, a `plan` model and a M2M relationship mapping both.
Translated in Django models, here is what it gives:

```py
class Plan(models.Model):
    duration = models.DurationField()
    # other fields

class User(AbstractUser):
    plans = models.ManyToMany(Plan, through="UserPlan")
    # other fields

class UserPlan(models.Model):
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entered = models.DateTimeField()
```

I would (almost) never recommand using a cron job to delete relationships. Use it as an history of passed data as you may need it to justify passed subscriptions once they have ended. I say almost since some legislation might force you to absolutely delete all data if they are not necessary (probably depends of what kind of subscriptions we are talking about).

I see you also used Groups and not directly Plans. I would use my approach since you can use  [DRF permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) easily to check if they are part of the plan and if they exceeded the duration time. It also lets you add other fields for renewal of plans.

*As a conclusion*, I would say there is not a definite way to design a REST API in general, but try to keep it simple and separate each parts to make it clear.